Managing Internal Service Calls in DDD Application Layer Without Excessive DTO Mapping
I’m developing an application using DDD with a Domain, an Application, and an Infrastructure layer.
Inside my Domain, I have my entities with business logic and some domain services. In the Application layer, I have higher-level services that I call Managers. These Managers receive DTOs, map them to Domain objects to access validators, methods, and business logic, apply modifications, and then map the results back to DTOs to return.
Within the Application layer, I occasionally need one Manager to call another Manager. However, since Managers use DTOs for both input and output, this results in a lot of redundant code for mapping DTOs to domain objects and vice versa. Specifically, it involves:

Mapping input DTO to Domain object.
Calling another Manager with the DTO.
Receiving a DTO as a result.
Mapping the result DTO back to a Domain object.
Mapping the final result back to a DTO for the Infrastructure layer.

This repetitive mapping leads to unnecessary boilerplate code.
So I'm trying to encapsulate the internal logic within internal services that use Domain entities directly and could be injected into my Managers. This way, I can create public methods in my managers which rely on my internal services and are only accessible to the Infrastructure layer, while avoiding the need to pass DTOs between Managers, reducing redundant mapping and without directly exposing my Domain entities.
But if I use internal services and internal interfaces, I lose the power of dependency injection. When attempting to inject an internal interface into a service within the Infrastructure layer, I receive the following error:

Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Interface' is less accessible than method 'Constructor'

If I make my interfaces public, I still can implement them in internal services, but it also make them available in external layers such as the Infrastructure. I want my Infrastructure to rely to my Managers only.
What is the usual solution for this problem, is it even a thing or people usually accept mapping overload? Should I use DTOs between my Application Services?

Shared mapping code
I solved this by creating mapping extension classes.
# An example usage in C#
User user = userDto.ToDomain();

The ToDomain() is an extension method in its own static class. Having them separated from managers allows multiple managers to use the same Dto. It's usefulness becomes apparent if you decide to break apart your managers into vertical slices or per feature (eg: UserEditManager, UserPasswordResetManager)
Using Domain Service
Consider avoiding manager-to-manager calls. For shared domain code, I've created a "Domain Service".

Accepts only Domain entities and lives in the domain layer.
✅ Solves the problem of boilerplate domain code between application services (or managers in your case), by combining domain related code.
✅ Solves the problem of transactional operations between managers/application-services (without transactional operations, database can get into an "unfinished state" if one part failed to save due to an error)
✅ Solves the problem of circular dependencies if your managers are initialized through dependency injection and the references have become complex that it causes a stackoverflow exception.

Domain Driven Design: Domain Service, Application Service
Domain services vs Application services
